# Como faço para usar input file multiple do html5 fazer ele selecionar dois arquivos de diretorio diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Pessoal estou com uma questão, como faço para usar input file multiple do html5 fazer ele selecionar dois arquivos da seguinte forma: o usuario seleciona o primeiro arquivo depois o dialog é fechado quando o arquivo é selecionado dai ele seleciona outro arquivo(abrindo o dialog do input file) de outro diretorio dai o input file incrementa resultando em dois arquivos.

já tentei mas meu input sempre substitui o anterior, alguem sabe me dizer uma maneira de selecionar dois arquivos de diretorio diferente?

Comment: Acho (acho) que isso é impossível. Os input file, até onde sei, são apenas para leitura, portanto não tem como inserir ou tirar nada deles. O que vc pode fazer é criar ou apagar apenas. Pra fazer algo parecido, teria que criar alguma artimanha que SIMULE isso.

Comment: @dvd Não acho que vc não entendeu , eu não quero mudar o input eu só disse o que ele faz quando se seleciona dois arquivos. O caso é, tem a possibilidade de selecionar dois arquivos de diretórios diferentes ? Por que eu tenho um exemplo de outro codigo de terceiro que ele faz isso mas não to conseguindo extrair esse codigo

Comment: eu consigo por exemplo nesse exemplo do site http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php selecionar dois arquivos de diretorio diferente

Comment: não numa pasta diferente, os dois arquivos estao em pasta diferentes

Comment: Eu perguntei foi se vc quer selecionar 2 arquivos em pastas diferentes usando o mesmo diálogo.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Pois então, vê nesse site aqui http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php ele consegue selecionar mais arquivos mesmo fechando o dialog no modo multiple

Comment: Deve ser algo parecido com isso https://jsfiddle.net/dz362qq7/ .. vai adicionando arquivos e depois pegas todos como Array no PHP.

Comment: ficou bacana é bem parecida a ideia , mas como faço para submeter os selecionados

Comment: por que os itens não aparecem selecionados no input file

Comment: Os que foram selecionados estão ocultos

Comment: para submeter, é só submeter o form normalmente

Comment: Entendi vou tentar aqui